# Passing in multiple variables into an Apollo Query component

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

```
const GET_DOG_PHOTO = gql`
  query Dog($breed: String!) {
    dog(breed: $breed) {
      id
      displayImage
    }
  }
`;

const DogPhoto = ({ breed }) => (
  <Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed }}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return null;
      if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

      return (
        <img src={data.dog.displayImage} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

Im looking at the documentation and i can see that they have passed a props called breed in the variables property of the Query component. What if the query takes 2 arguments, how do you pass in 2 parameters?

Comment: `{{ breed }}` is just an object declaration syntax ... then simply `{{ breed, sthElse }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [ES2015 Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). These two syntax are equivalent.

```
  <Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed }}>
  <Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed: breed }}>
```

Then, if you have a query with 2 params like so:

```
const GET_DOG_PHOTO = gql`
  query Dog($breed: String!, $size: Int!) {
    dog(breed: $breed, size: $size) {
      id
      displayImage
    }
  }
`;
```

The query component will look like this

```
function DogPhoto({ breed, size }) => 
  return (
    <Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed, size }}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return null;
        if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

        return (
          <img src={data.dog.displayImage} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  )
};
```

Comment: I am trying something like                                                                                             ````const GET_DOG_PHOTO = gql`
  query Dog($order: String!) {
    dog(order_by: {size: $order}) {
      id
      displayImage
    }
  }
`;

Comment: but it is not working...I want to pass the order by value as a parameter

Comment: It look like what you are doing is right. What is not working exactly?

Comment: Error: GraphQL error: undefined
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:60)
    at bundle.esm.js:1488
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.<anonymous> (bundle.esm.js:1486)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at tslib.es6.js:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:67)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1464)

Comment: any problem for passing "asc" or "desc" as a string. once I got the error saying something related to "enum". I forgot what change I had made

Comment: I believe that this is not directly related and needs to be a separate question. Please create a new StackOverflow question with all code necessary to reproduce and paste the link here